# Rust: Prime numbers

Tags: primes, rust

A first attempt to implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find all the prime numbers from 2 up to a given number resulted in this brute force algorithm. A user pointed out, that this is in fact not the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but just a brute force algorithm and should be reviewed as such.

```
#![feature(inclusive_range_syntax)]

pub fn primes_up_to(limit: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut vec: Vec<u64> = (2...limit).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for p in 2...limit {
        vec.retain(|&x| x <= p || x % p != 0);
    }

    vec
}
```

Comment: This is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes it is just a brute force method of computing primes up to a certain number.

Comment: @Dair, I'm incredible sorry that I've mislead you. I also mislead myself. But thanks to your comment, I realize my foolishness. Even though I was heavenly influenced by reading about the Sieve, this isn't it. I changed the title and hopefully made clear, that this is not what I originally thought it was. Thanks again for pointing this out multiple times.

Comment: Don't feel too bad; that is a very common mistake to make about the Sieve.

Comment: [Related -- The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes.](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) (external link)

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty straight-forward, only minor nits:

1. You don't need the turbofish on `collect`; the type declaration on the `let` is enough of a hint.
2. That type doesn't need to specify the type of the vector element, it can be inferred.
3. Really reaching for straws, the `p` and `x` variables could be a bit longer, or `x % p != 0` could be made into a function with a name, just so that there's no mental overhead in reading the code.

```
pub fn primes_up_to(limit: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut vec: Vec<_> = (2...limit).collect();

    for p in 2...limit {
        vec.retain(|&x| x <= p || x % p != 0);
    }

    vec
}
```

Comment: Probably more important than these points is that he didn't actually implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes...